# Bind Control Resource variable to DataContext

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding

What I am trying to do is to create a variable in my (xaml) control resources and bind it to a property on my DataContext (e.g. ViewModel).

I am willing to have in my `xaml`, something like this

```
<system:Boolean x:Key="MyVariable" Value={Binding MyDataContextProperty}/>
```

I know that are more elegant ways to do it, e.g declare `MyVariable` to DataContext (e.g. ViewModel) and use it from there. However for testing reasons I want to explore the aforementioned aspect.

Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> A 'Binding' can only be set on a DependencyProperty of a DependencyObject.

so no, `<system:Boolean x:Key="MyVariable" Value={Binding MyDataContextProperty}/>` will not work

it is possible to declare a constant bool value in Resources

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <system:Boolean x:Key="varBool">
            True
        </system:Boolean>
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{StaticResource varBool}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

also possible to make a special DependencyObject

```
public class SomeObj: DependencyObject
{
    public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof (bool), typeof (SomeObj), 
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

    public bool Value
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

bindings will work

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <local:SomeObj x:Key="varBool1" Value="True"/>
        <local:SomeObj x:Key="varBool2" Value="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource varBool1} }"/>
    </StackPanel.Resources>

    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource varBool1}}"/>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value, Source={StaticResource varBool2}}"/>
</StackPanel>
```

the main question is why do all this if there is already `MyDataContextProperty`?

Comment: The only reason I am trying something like this is 'curiosity'. Of course this curiosity derived from the business logic behind my case, which I think the full extend of it will not help anyone and that is why I omitted it.

Comment: Elsewhere I've seen this "trick" used, but with the DependencyProperty declared as public static **readonly** - is there a significant difference ?

Comment: @T4NK3R,indeed, i should have added **readonly** here in DP declaration to protect it from modifications in outside code (without **readonly** keyword this assignment - `SomeObj.ValueProperty =  DependencyProperty.Register(...)` - is valid). but in the context of the question i don't see diference